# Linking material emission value with light power for easy animation

Tags: light, fcurves

I have a flickering lightbulb.
It consists of a point light and a lightbulb mesh with an emission material for when it's on.

I'm using a noise modifier to variate the lightbulb power, but I'd like to link the power value to the emission strength.
I know I can just copy the modifier from the point light fcurve to the emission, but it's a hassle. I change one I have to change the other. Also consider the emission strength is exponential in its visual effect - 0.0 - 1.0 massive variation, but as you get higher the difference is less and less noticeable, unlike the point light where the strength value has a comparatively linear effect.

Any ideas?

Comment: For the strength issue, try using the power option on the math node to exponentially increase the lights power. Then you could connect it to the emission strength.

Comment: but how do I link the point light strength with the material's emission strength at all?

Comment: I worked it out! Added a driver to a value node linking to the light's energy property! Working perfectly :D